# I am setting up SQL Server Express 2008 R2, how do 'Service Accounts' work

Tags: sql-server, windows

Ok I am setting up SQL Server Express 2008 R2 and I am at the following screen:

[image]

What do I need to do here. Can I just press next? I'm guessing if I press next it will work but is this what you're really supposed to do?

Basically I don't fully understand what's going on here and I don't just wan't to keep hitting next as I know it will come back to bit me in the ass later.

Thanks

Comment: This probably belongs on Serverfault, although I guess maybe the OP want to set up a development machine.

Comment: That's correct, I'm setting up a development machine so need to know what options will get me the optimum development environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, just press next.

Basicall SQL2008 is asking you which system user should run the database executables. If you are installing this in your own developer machine I wouldnt worry too much about it.

If you are installing this on a DEV, UAT or LIVE server then I would pay more attention to who is running these processes, you can pick a specific account but SYSTEM, NETWORK SERVICE are all good choices.

Comment: Agreed - if it's a dev machine, I'd start the SQL Server Browser service, too.

Comment: And as you the answer states, if this is going to be live, make sure you have a good understanding of what you need to do.  Make a new user account and give it the minimum necessary privileges to run SQL.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx?ppud=4 has a great explanation.